# How to insert list into nested list in python?

Tags: python

Right now I am practicing List
I am facing a problem of inserting nested list.
for instance; I have a nested list and i want to make another nested.

example

```
a = [[1, 'a', 2], [2, 'a', 3], [3, 'b', 4], [4, 'c', 5]]
```

output should be:

```
output = [['a'[1,2],[2,3]], ['b'[3],[4]], ['c'[4],[5]]]
```

Comment: How it's valid `['a'[1,2],[2,3]]`?

Comment: Your output doesn't appear to be syntactically correct, could you fix it?

Comment: Use a dictionary keyed by the string in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to collect all the sublists with the same string.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [[1, 'a', 2], [2, 'a', 3], [3, 'b', 4], [4, 'c', 5]]
output_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [[], []])

for num1, key, num2 in a:
    output_dict[key][0].append(num1)
    output_dict[key][1].append(num2)

output = [[key, *val] for key, val in output_dict.items()]
```

`output` is

```
[['a', [1, 2], [2, 3]], ['b', [3], [4]], ['c', [4], [5]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an list, however, a dictionary is probably better in your use case.

```
a = [[1, 'a', 2], [2, 'a', 3], [3, 'b', 4], [4, 'c', 5]]
dct = {}
for arr in a:
    key = arr[1]
    del arr[1]
    if key not in dct:
        dct[key] = [arr]
    else:
        dct[key].append(arr)

print(dct)  # => {'a': [[1, 2], [2, 3]], 'b': [[3, 4]], 'c': [[4, 5]]}
```

If you need a list, then you can use list comprehension to turn the dictionary into a list

```
lst = [[key, *dct[key]] for key in dct]
print(lst)  # => [['a', [1, 2], [2, 3]], ['b', [3, 4]], ['c', [4, 5]]]
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This answer is also completely valid, is it not?